# Common Patterns and Designes in Android Studio

Tags: android, design-patterns

I just started with Android Studio. Since I have no experience with Android devices I was wandering if there are some patterns or designs or functions that are often used in Android. 
for Example: if you sway the phone in ios the backround picture moves with a little bit.. is there something simular in Android?

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/ The "Design" section will help you to learn the basics of the UX and when you are ready to develop, the "Develop" section will guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean UI design patterns give a look at:

- [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html). It gives you the rules to create the app UI according to the latest android guidelines

The most important in my opinion are:

- Navigation drawer: it creates a sliding menu
- FAB (Float Action Button)
- Toolbar

Hope it helps you